# How should i prove every finite lattice is bounded?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to know the outline to how to prove every finite lattice is bounded?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a lower bound on [two lattice points by taking their meet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) (resp. an upper bound by taking their join).  If [a lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29) has only finitely many points, this "two at a time" approach can be repeated (a finite number of times) to get a common lower bound (resp. common upper bound) on all the points.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a lattice is that for any two elements, they must have a join and a meet.  The proof is by contradiction.  Assume that a finite lattice is not bounded.  This means that there is no single element that is a maximum or that there is no single element that is a minimum.  Since the lattice is finite, however, there are a finite number of maxima and of minima, which can be identified by starting from all pairs of elements and following their joins or meets, respectively, until the join or meet is identical to one of the current pair.  The element obtained is one of the maxima or one of the minima, respectively.  By the assumption, either or both of the sets of maxima and minima have cardinality greater than one.  Therefore, there exist two elements in the finite lattice that have no join and/or have no meet.  This contradicts the definition of a lattice, which requires any two elements to have a join and a meet.  Ergo the assumption of an unbounded finite lattice is false.  QED.

Comment: You considered $L$ to be unbounded in the start of your proof. But in the third line, you used $L$ is finite.

Answer (score -2):

Let the lattice $L$ has $n$ elements and the elements of the lattice is $a_1, a_2, \dotso ,a_n$

Now, $$a_1\lor a_2\lor\dotso\lor a_n= (\dotso((a_1\lor a_2)\lor a_3)\dotso a_n-1)\lor a_n)$$ [since $\lor$ is associative].

Since between $L$ is a lattice, between any pair of elements $a_i$ and $a_j$, $(a_i\lor a_j)$ exists,
So, $$(...((a_1\lor a_2)\lor a_3)\dotso a_n-1)\lor a_n)$$ does exist as well.

Similarly we can show if $L$ is a lattice with finite elements then a minimum element does exists.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).